May this function case thread to wait indefinitely?
I am reading the code in flutter engine at
https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/main/shell/common/platform_view.cc#L58
I want to ask that if latch.Signal() is reached before latch.Wait(), will it wait indefinitely? If this case will never happen, how it is ensured?
void PlatformView::NotifyCreated() {
  std::unique_ptr<Surface> surface;
  // Threading: We want to use the platform view on the non-platform thread.
  // Using the weak pointer is illegal. But, we are going to introduce a latch
  // so that the platform view is not collected till the surface is obtained.
  auto* platform_view = this;
  fml::ManualResetWaitableEvent latch;
  fml::TaskRunner::RunNowOrPostTask(
      task_runners_.GetRasterTaskRunner(), [platform_view, &surface, &latch]() {
        surface = platform_view->CreateRenderingSurface();
        if (surface && !surface->IsValid()) {
          surface.reset();
        }
        latch.Signal();
      });
  latch.Wait();
  if (!surface) {
    FML_LOG(ERROR) << "Failed to create platform view rendering surface";
    return;
  }
  delegate_.OnPlatformViewCreated(std::move(surface));
}


explain the code detail and some more information about the mutex it uses. Analyze CPU scheduling possibilities.

if you look at its current implementation
the latch has a boolean that it sets when signaled, then when Wait happens later it sees the boolean was already set and it doesn't wait.
